Building an AOSP app with maven dependency
I am building an AOSP system app which depends upon the Wireguard tunnel library.
The Android.bp file is as follows:
android_app {
    name: "VPN",
    srcs: [
        "java/**/*.kt",
    ],
    resource_dirs: [
        "res"
    ],
    manifest: "AndroidManifest.xml",
}

How do I add a dependency on an external dependency?
I have tried downloading the AAR file from Maven and including is in the Android.bp file, then including it in static_libs on the android_app.
android_library_import {
    name: "wireguard-lib",
    aars: [
        "libs/tunnel-1.0.20230706.aar",
    ],
    sdk_version: "current",
    extract_jni: true,
}


Try the following:
android_library_import {
    name: "wireguard-lib",
    aars: ["libs/tunnel-1.0.20230706.aar"],
}

android_app {
    name: "VPN",
    srcs: [
        "java/**/*.kt",
    ],
    resource_dirs: [
        "res"
    ],
    manifest: "AndroidManifest.xml",
    static_libs: ["wireguard-lib"],
}

